# Something loads something

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context

I read this line in a book:

> The dried grass loads the wagon.

As far as I know it should be passive:

> The dried grass is loaded the wagon.

I have never seen this structure that **something loads something**. Always the subject of this structure is a person:

> David loads the wagon.

Can anybody tell me in the first quote what is the meaning of "to load"?

Comment: A 50-pound weight loads the scale.  A 50-watt light bulb loads the circuit.

Comment: @HotLicks So do you mean "to load" here means "to fill"?

Comment: I mean that "to load" here means "to burden".

Comment: @HotLicks I don't think so. The wagon can be burdened or loaded with dried grass, but dried grass cannot burdens or loads the wagon. It is not grammatically correct.

Comment: I agree with @HotLicks.  On dictionary.com (i.e., https://www.dictionary.com/browse/load?s=t - see def. 18) "load" is defined as "to weigh down, burden, or oppress."  Just as readily as I might say, "I don't want to burden you with my problems," I can say, "I don't want my problems to burden you."  Likewise, I can say, "I weighed down the wagon with grass," but I can also say, "Grass weighed down the wagon."  In fact, according to definition 22, I could also rightly say, "The wagon loads the dried grass."

Comment: @Connoisseur - If X can be burdened by Y then Y can burden X.  Standard transitive usage.

Comment: Connoisseur - rocks load the truck. Normal. Standard,

Comment: "is loaded the wagon" is not grammatical. Did you mean "is loaded into the wagon"?

Answer (score 2):

> **[load](https://www.dictionary.com/browse/load?s=t)** - ...18. to weigh down, burden, or oppress (often followed by down, with, on, etc.)

A definition of "load" is "to weigh down, burden, or oppress."

Just as I can say, "I weighed down the tarp with a bunch of rocks," I can also just as properly say, "A bunch of rocks weighed down the tarp." The verb's object, "a bunch of rocks," in the first sentence serves just as well as the subject of that same verb as we see in the second sentence.

Likewise, just as I can say, "I don't want to burden you with my problems," I can also just as properly say, "I don't want my problems to burden you."  The object of "to burden" in the first sentence, "my problems," can just as well be the subject of that same verb as we see in the second sentence.

Finally, I can say, "We oppress minorities with systematized racism," but I can also properly say, "Systematized racism oppresses minorities."  In this example as well, the object of the verb can also be the subject of the verb.  And to be clear, these examples are *not* employing the passive voice.  The passive voice of the first sentence would be, "Minorities are oppressed by us with systematized racism," and of the second sentence would be, "Minorities are oppressed by systematized racism."

In fact, according to definition 22, I could also properly say, "The wagon loads the dried grass."

Anyway, just as in the examples above, the verb "load" can be used such that just as I might say, "He loads the wagon with the dried grass," I can also properly say, "The dried grass loads the wagon," the passive voice of which would be, "The wagon is loaded by the dried grass," not "The dried grass is loaded the wagon."

Comment: "The dried grass loads the wagon" is not something a native English speaker would say. And "The wagon loads the dried grass" means that the wagon is actively placing the dried grass onto something. If you want to convince us that this usage is correct, please show examples of it being used.

Comment: Not true, as evidenced by the quotation from the book, by the example in the dictionary I cited, and by the examples in every English dictionary.  By the way, while you deign yourself such, you are not a spokesperson for native English speakers.  So, what say we let the dictionaries with all their researchers and data on word usage by native English speakers speak for native English speakers in regards to the meaning of words and how they're used.

Comment: "quotation from the book": Which book? We don't know what the book the OP is quoting. It may be self-published by a poor English speaker."example in the dictionary I cited". The examples in the dictionary you cited all have either the person placing the burden or bearing the burden as the subject. You have cited no examples in which the load itself is the subject. So like I said, please quote some actual cases for this. (And look up "deign" while you are about it.)

Answer (score -2):

**The first two sentences you quote, both passive and active, are both wrong.**

Although definition 18 which you could could be interpreted to mean  that the subject of the verb 'load' is the thing that is the burden, you will notice that in both the example sentences for it the subject is the person applying the burden to the object.

> to feel loaded down with responsibilities; to load oneself with obligations

Although it is not obvious from the definition, when 'load' is used in this sense the subject should be the person (or other animate object) who places the burden, not the burden itself.

> CORRECT: I loaded the wagon (with grass)
>
> INCORRECT: The grass loaded the wagon

Comment: Downvoter care to explain?